# Prompting AVAudioPlayer to play based on a timer

Tags: objective-c, ios, avaudioplayer, nstimer, uiswitch

I am trying to setup a stopwatch alarm that is enabled via UISwitch. I want the alarm to be triggered after an x amount of secs after the timer has started. I have an ivar int variable (timerCount) that holds the amount of secs that has passed and I want to play a sound based on that ivar. When the timer begins and I enable the switch I would hope that the player would fire at 10 secs, but that is not the case. I know the "if statement" is the culprit because when I remove it the AVPlayer will play the wav file when the switch is enabled. I just need another set of eyeballs to look at this and figure out what I missed.
Here is the code snippet:

```
- (IBAction)timerSound{

    if (voiceSwitch.on){

    NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"horn"
                                                         ofType:@"wav"];

    NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: fileURL error: nil];

    if (timerCount == 10)

    [self.player play];

    }

    else {
        [self.player stop];
    }
}
```

Comment: `timerCount` holds time interval since ...?

Comment: It's set to 0 when the start button is pressed and increments every second.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`playAt:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008067-CH1-SW26).

Example based on yours –

```
- (IBAction)valueChanged:(id)sender {
    UISwitch *aSwitch = (UISwitch*)sender;
    if ( aSwitch.on ) {
        NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"horn"
                                                                  ofType:@"wav"];

        NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

        audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL 
                                                                error:nil];

        [audioPlayer playAtTime:(audioPlayer.deviceCurrentTime + 3)];
    } else {
        [audioPlayer stop];
    }
}

- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag {
    [self.theSwitch setOn:NO animated:YES];

    [player release];
}
```

Comment: I went a different direction where I used the UISwitch to disable the AVAudioPlayer and set up the player in a method that is updated by a NSTimer and increments an integer. Then I use a switch statement to play at the desired time.